# Which Horizon "Post Transaction" responses are final and immutable?

Tags: horizon, transactions

I am working on the development of a software wallet. I am using [Horizon Post Transaction API](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/transactions-create.html) to post signed transaction. Following an [issue](https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/2483) I ran into, I am trying to understand which responses are final and immutable and which are provisional.

#### Timeout - Provisional

According to [this](https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/2483#issuecomment-613038158), [timeout](https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/timeout) is not a final answer:

> A stellar-core instance may drop your transaction after failing to include it in several ledgers (currently 3). However other distributed instances may still rebroadcast the tx. See e.g. stellar/stellar-core#1811.
>
> When Horizon provides you with a timeout, it means that Horizon has not had timely confirmation that your tx has made it into a ledger. It does not guarantee that the tx will never make it.

#### Success - Final & Immutable

According to [this](https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/2483#issuecomment-616711283), success is considered final & immutable:

> Success is a consensus-level return so you don't need to look it up again. You can see this is so because the response includes the result XDR, and such XDR could only come from stellar-core after ledger application.

#### Transaction malformed?

Are [transaction_malformed](https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/transaction_malformed) results final & immutable?

#### Transaction failed with transaction result_code == `tx_failed`?

Are [transaction_failed](https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/transaction_failed) results with transaction result_code == `tx_failed` like this [one](https://horizon.stellar.org/transactions/10e2a3481e3e967024cbee0db82a05a6a97c1f68d79342bb13ca20fb2ccf85a9) final & immutable?

I assume they are, as they include the result XDR like the aforementioned success result.

#### Transaction failed with transaction result_code != `tx_failed`?

What about [transaction_failed](https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/transaction_failed) results with transaction result_code != `tx_failed`?

Sample transaction results codes are:

- `tx_bad_auth`
- `tx_no_source_account`
- `tx_bad_seq`

These are trickier since the HTTP response body includes a result XDR as you mentioned but the transaction failure will not appear on the chain like the previous case when transaction result_code == `tx_failed` and fees are deducted. In general, such transactions may soon be valid, if account sequence changes for example.

Can I treat such results as final and immutable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, there are two cases when the transaction fails: during validation and during execution. The rule of thumb: ***any transaction that has been recorded on the ledger is final and immutable***. So if you can fetch it from Horizon, it means that the transaction is final.

Transactions that were **rejected** during the [validation phase](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/transactions.html#validity-of-a-transaction), and thus weren't included in the ledger, can be resubmitted (even without modifications). There is a key difference in behavior between those two cases.

If a transaction passes preliminary checks (it's not malformed, the fee is correct, all fields are set, the transaction is signed, timebounds restrictions are met, etc.), it is included in the candidate transaction set and then applied on the ledger. In this case, even if the transaction is **failed**, the validator **increments the sequence number** of the source account and **charges tx fees**.

Therefore,

- `success` - final, transaction passed
- `tx_failed` - final, transaction failed, no point to resubmit since the source sequence has changed and it will be rejected during validation upon next submission
- `timeout` - provisional, you need to either resubmit transaction as-is or increase fees before resubmission if surge pricing is in effect (check the [`/fee_stats` endpoint](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/fee-stats.html))
- `transaction_malformed`, `tx_no_source_account` - rejected during validation, no point to resubmit as it will never succeed
- `tx_bad_auth`, `tx_bad_seq` - rejected during validation, might become valid in the future, say, once the sequence or signers of the source account are changed, but from a wallet perspective it makes sense to treat it the same way `transaction_malformed` is handled since it's hard to automatically determine when this tx can be resubmitted

Comment: I am currently implementing the transaction posting mechanism. I know that in case of timeout, the transaction may still be included later in the blockchain without the wallet posting it again explicitly. Therefore I must treat this response as provisional. I am trying to understand if there is any chance that other failures (`transaction_malformed`, `tx_no_source_account`, `tx_bad_auth`, `tx_bad_seq`...) will later end up with the transaction in the blockchain **without** the wallet posting it again explicitly.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, for `timeout` case it's better to resubmit the transaction. You are losing nothing if it was already processed (it won't be applied second time), but if it was discarded earlier by the mempol (like in case of surge pricing) it helps to ensure that transaction is processed. 
All **rejected** statuses (`tx_bad_auth`,`tx_bad_seq`,`transaction_malformed`, etc.) actually mean that the transaction has been discarded before processing and won't ever be applied unless you'll explicitly try to submit it later.

Comment: Are there forks in Stellar? Could it be that I get a `success` and then there is a fork which does not contain the transaction?

Comment: In theory it's possible, but on practice it will take the entire network to conspire against you, deliberately rewriting transactions history. And I doubt such a thing may happen, as validators will carry tremendous losses in case if the network trust is compromised.

Comment: We have monitors which post simple transactions with a single XLM payment ~10 times per hour in order to monitor our Stellar integration. I found a case a couple of weeks ago in which we got a Horizon timeout response after 30 seconds. We attempted to post again and failed on `tx_bad_seq`. We treated it as a failure. We were surprised to find the transaction on the chain: https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/tx/45a9674370754d50b50df23e03d7fa87bd6ee70bd2db2431a8ab874218c3115a.
I filed this as a new Horizon issue: https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/2628

Comment: This should be fixed by [#2601](https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/2628) to be released as part of [1.4.0](https://github.com/stellar/go/releases/tag/horizon-v1.4.0). It is expected to arrived to horizon.stellar.org on June 10, 2020.

This means `tx_bad_seq` can be treated as final and immutable.